# C++ Two classes that need each other in constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have two very similar classes in a .h file that need each other in the constructor. It's about a Color class and one will use unsigned char 0 to 255 as RGB and the other will use floats 0.0 to 1.0 as RGB and I need to be able to convert from one and other in the constructor and assignment operators and other member functions.

**Color3.h:**

```
class Color3 {
    public:
    unsigned char R, G, B;
    Color3()
    : R(0), G(0), B(0) {

    }

    Color3(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
    : R(r), G(g), B(b) {

    }

    Color3(const Color3f& other)
    : R(other.R*255), G(other.G*255), B(other.B*255) {

    }
};


class Color3f {
    public:
    float R, G, B;
    Color3f()
    : R(0), G(0), B(0) {

    }

    Color3f(float r, float g, float b)
    : R(r), G(g), B(b) {

    }

    Color3f(const Color3& other)
    : R(other.R/255), G(other.G/255), B(other.B/255) {

    }
};
```

Can I put them in separate files without getting into an circular (*I believe that's how it is called*) include? I think I know the answer to this question but I want to know what other solutions might be out there. I would prefer them to be in the same file but if there's no other way then I'll separate them.

Comment: Please write the code without obvious errors and it would be better if you yourself try compile what you wrote. In your class Color3f constructor is named as Color3

Comment: sorry I fixed the code (copy > paste never brought me something good)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you use a *forward declaration*. For example:

```
class Color3f; // <--- Forward declaration

class Color3
{
public:
    unsigned char R, G, B;
    Color3()
        : R(0), G(0), B(0)
    {

    }
    Color3(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
        : R(r), G(g), B(b)
    {

    }

    // Can't define this yet with only an incomplete type.
    inline Color3(const Color3f& other);
};


class Color3f
{
public:
    float R, G, B;
    Color3f()
        : R(0), G(0), B(0)
    {

    }
    Color3f(float r, float g, float b)
        : R(r), G(g), B(b)
    {

    }
    Color3f(const Color3& other)
        : R(other.R/255), G(other.G/255), B(other.B/255)
    {

    }
};

// Color3f is now a complete type, so define the conversion ctor.
Color3::Color3(const Color3f& other)
        : R(other.R*255), G(other.G*255), B(other.B*255)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect :) I'll vote it as solved as soon as the 15 minutes time limit have passed.

Comment: ...cough.. *inline*... (if this is all in a header). And +1 btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Hint taken. Edited.

Comment: @WhozCraig why does the *inline* have to be there?

Comment: @SanduLiviuCatalin Because if its all in a header and you implement the constructor out-of-class-def *and* include the header in multiple .cpp files you're linker will bark about duplicate symbols being defined. If the constructor is implemented in a .cpp file it should *not* be marked inline.

Answer (score 0):

These situations are what '[pragma once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)' is for. Just add it to the top of your .h file and it will only be included once:

```
#pragma once
```

However, make sure that it is only an 'include' loop, and not an actual functionality loop. It looks like your constructors might actually cause I loop when instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a declaration of the other class to the top of your header file to avoid circular dependence problem. For example:

```
class Color3;
```

at the top of `Color3f.h`, and same for the other class. Combined with `#pragma once` or `#ifndef` include guard, the program can compile fine with split files.

But classes this similar should really be declared as the same class specialized with different template parameters. For example `Color3<unsigned char>` and `Color3<float>`.

Comment: Templating these kind of classes would mess up the methods since unsigned char RGB operations aren't the same as float RGB operations and. I thought of doing it like this but that means I should write overloaded methods for unsigned char and float values.